# Relative pronouns for time (span)

Tags: word-choice, pronoun, time

> Hätten Sie am Dienstag zwischen 10-11 etwas Zeit, 'wann'/'wo'/'in der' ich anrufen könnte?

Which relative pronoun do I have to use in the question above?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Wann` is not possible.

`Wo` is colloquially used although a stylistic mistake and shouldn't be used in written language.

`In der` and `während der` would be the best solutions with `während der` being a little bit higher in register (this could be positive or negative, depending on the situation).

Alternatives would be

> Könnte ich Sie am Dienstag zwischen 10 und 11 anrufen?

and the ones proposed by chirlu.

Comment: Disagree that "wo" is a stylistic mistake - It's perfectly valid.

Answer (score 9):

In my opinion, the best form would be *so daß* (*so dass* in new orthography):

> Hätten Sie am Dienstag zwischen zehn und elf etwas Zeit, so daß ich Sie anrufen könnte?

If you want to know when it would be the most appropriate time to call in a larger span, I’d ask one of these:

> Wann könnte ich Sie am Dienstag am besten anrufen?
>
> Zu welcher Zeit könnte ich Sie am Dienstag am besten anrufen?

---

To answer the general question, the prepositions to use with *Zeit* as a point in time are usually *zu* and *um* and can often be used interchangeably:

> Zu welcher Zeit kann ich anrufen? Um welche Zeit kann ich anrufen?
>
> Warst du zu der Zeit schon hier? Warst du um die Zeit schon hier?

For a time span, it is mostly *in*:

> Die Straße ist in der Zeit von 12 bis 18 Uhr gesperrt.

Comment: Also: Hätten Sie am Dienstag zwischen zehn und elf Uhr etwas Zeit damit ich Sie anrufen kann?

Answer (score 0):

It was a big surprise for me as a native speaker that "wo" is also standard German in this case. It is neither considered "wrong" nor "umgangssprachlich".

The first time, I read about it, was here:
https://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-das-schoenste-wo-gibt-a-421249.html

> An dem ehemännlichen Versprechen "In dem Jahr, wo wir Weihnachten mal
> nicht zu deinen Eltern fahren, bekommst du von mir einen Pelzmantel"
> können allenfalls Tierschützer Anstoß nehmen. Denn die Verwendung des
> Wortes "wo" ist auch bei Zeitangaben zulässig. Wer sich auf den Moment
> freut, wo die Tänzerin aus der Torte springt, der kann dies reinen
> Gewissens tun. Er muss nicht auf den Moment warten, in dem das
> geschieht.

All grammar books that I have checked, after reading that, agree in this point.