# Niveau von "wo" als Relativpronomen für Ortsangaben

Tags: usage, pronoun

> (a) Das ist das Lokal, in dem er die Frau trifft.
>
> (b) Das ist das Lokal, wo er die Frau trifft.

Satz (a) klingt auf jeden Fall formell. Wie formell klingt Satz (b), verglichen mit (a)? Ist er ebenso formell?

(Hier einige Fragen über die Formalität von "wo" als Relativpronomen für vierschiedene *Zeitangaben*: [heute](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17834/relative-pronoun-for-heute), [Momente](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5177/ist-die-benutzung-des-w%C3%B6rtchens-wo-in-zusammenhang-mit-zeitangaben-korrekt), [etwas Zeit](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6899/relative-pronouns-for-time-span). In dieser Frage geht es um "wo" als Relativpronomen für *Ortsangaben*.)

Comment: Gute Frage, auch wenn ich befürchte, dass es mehr Meinungen als fundierte Antworten geben wird. Daher meine nur als Kommentar: ich würde (a) schreiben. Ob ich immer (a) sagen würde, weiß ich nicht. Die Konstruktion "dort, wo" ist, wo ich die Rolle von "wo" als Relativpronomen sehe.

Comment: Übrigens auch, mit leicht anderer Bedeutung: "In dem Lokal ist, wo er die Frau trifft."

Comment: (a) ist sicherlich richtig, aber (b) deswegen nicht falsch. Es gibt auch Konstellationen, bei denen "wo" die eindeutig bessere Wahl ist ("Hoch vom Dachstein an, wo der Aar noch haust ...")

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Ich würde nahezu immer "wo" bevorzugen, auch schriftlich. Eventuell würde ich mir in einer Doktorarbeit Gedanken drüber machen...falls es mir überhaupt auffällt.

Comment: Anders wäre es bei:
Das Lokal, das Dir gefiel.
Das Lokal, wo Dir gefiel.

Comment: "Wo" wäre auch richtig, wenn er die Frau vor dem Lokal trifft. Dann wäre zwar "vor dem" konkreter, aber die, die sich unterhalten, wissen vielleicht nichts Genaueres, ob in dem Lokal oder bei dem Lokal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wenn es sich um eine Ortsangabe handelt, kann das Adverb [*wo*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wo_Fragewort_Relativpronomen#Bedeutung2a) anstelle einer Präposition + Relativpronomen als relativischer Anschluss verwendet werden.

> in einen Raum, wo …
>   in einen Raum, in dem …

Laut Duden – *Richtiges und gutes Deutsch* sind beide Konstruktionen korrekt. Im Gegensatz zu vielen anderen Zweifelsfällen gibt die Dudenredaktion für diesen Fall keine Empfehlung an.

Comment: Die Konstruktion ist im wesentlichen korrekt, allerdings nicht ideal. In der Hochsprache (z.B. Fernsehnachrichten) würde immer "in dem" verwendet. Sie ist allerdings deutlich korrekter als "wo" für Nominalphrasen: "Die Frau, wo er getroffen hat..."

Comment: @KilianFoth... wie kommst du denn darauf, dass es hochsprachlich nicht korrekt ist? Bzw ist dann die FAZ und die Welt und die Taz nicht hochsprachlich? https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1DVCJ_enDE430DE443&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=faz%20%22der%20ort%2C%20wo%22  https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1DVCJ_enDE430DE443&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22die+welt%22+%22der+ort%2C+wo%22  https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1DVCJ_enDE430DE443&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22taz%22+%22der+ort%2C+wo%22